# PTIJ: How do we know from the Megilla that Haman and Zeresh had a bad marriage?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> "וַיִּתְאַפַּק הָמָן, וַיָּבוֹא אֶל-בֵּיתוֹ; וַיִּשְׁלַח וַיָּבֵא אֶת-אֹהֲבָיו, וְאֶת-זֶרֶשׁ אִשְׁתּוֹ"
>
> "Haman refrained himself, and went home; and he sent and fetched his loved ones and Zeresh his wife." (Esther 5:10)

Why isn't Zeresh included in "his loved ones" (אֹהֲבָיו)?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's not "the ones he loved." It's "the one who loved him."

Comment: works both ways

Comment: ohavav is understood to be his supporters but not his family, and Zeresh is family. If this is a PTIJ, it should be noted in the title and with the disclaimer.

Comment: it is tagged PTIJ

Answer (score 1):

Answer: it must be because she didn't love him !